# Selenium with PHPUnit not loading page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am trying to make a test suit for a php project using phpunit and phpunit-selenium. In my composer file I have

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "^3.0"
}
```

The installed phpunit version is 5.7.4
I am using selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar as the selenium server. I start the server with
    java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Harlan\Selenium\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

In my test class I have

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
class UserSubscriptionTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {

public function setUp() {
    $this->setHost('localhost');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/cwckids/web/user/login');
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');


}

public function tearDown() {
    $this->stop();
}



public function testFormSubmissionWithUsername()
{
$this->byName('login-form[login]')->value('admin');
$this->byName('login-form[password]')->value('mypassword');
$this->byId('login-form')->submit();

$content = $this->byTag('body')->text();
$this->assertEquals('Everything is Good!', $content, 'something wrong!!');
}    
}
```

My problem is that the firefox browser opens up but doesn't load the page http://localhost/cwckids/web/user/login

The test fails immediately because it cannot find the elements. It give a message saying 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"login-form[login]"}

I couldn't find a solution for the problem. Is it some version incompatibility? I tried with a few versions of Firefox and also selenium server. My Firefox version is 50.1.0. If it is a version incompatibility can someone suggest correct versions? Thanks

The complete trace

C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest>phpunit tests/acceptance/UserSubscriptionTest.php
PHPUnit 5.7.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 6.51 seconds, Memory: 9.25MB

There was 1 error:

1) UserSubscriptionTest::testFormSubmissionWithUsername
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"login-form[login]"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-I0LAEAM', ip: '192.168.8.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php:165
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\CommandsHolder.php:108
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Element\Accessor.php:134
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Element\Accessor.php:175
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Element\Accessor.php:108
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:394
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\tests\acceptance\UserSubscriptionTest.php:66
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\tests\acceptance\UserSubscriptionTest.php:66
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:348
C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:314

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things I'd suggest changing:

You are missing a call to `$this->url();` from, what I can see within your test method:

```
public function testFormSubmissionWithUsername()
{
    $this->url('your actual URL here'); // Add this line
    $this->byName('login-form[login]')->value('admin');
    $this->byName('login-form[password]')->value('mypassword');
    $this->byId('login-form')->submit();

    $content = $this->byTag('body')->text();
    $this->assertEquals('Everything is Good!', $content, 'something wrong!!');
}
```

You are also not calling the `parent::setUp()` method from within your own setUp method:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    // Set your browser, port setup etc here
}
```

There's also no need to explicitly call `$this->stop();` from within tearDown, so remove that function completely.

Lastly, I'd tell selenium to take screenshots of failures, they save a lot of time:

```
/**
 * Override this method from \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase so we can capture a screenshot.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function onNotSuccessfulTest($exception)
{
    $filedata   = $this->currentScreenshot();
    $file       = YOUR_SCREENSHOT_DIR . '\testfails\\' . basename(get_class($this)) . '.png';
    file_put_contents($file, $filedata);

    parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($exception);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer really helped. Not sure why $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/cwckids/web/user/login'); doesn't set the url, but your solution works fine. I like the screenshot idea too. Thanks